# Data flow analysis - IN OUT

Tags: compiler-construction, data-analysis, compiler-optimization, dataflow

I could not understand why "001 1100" is the result in the part I drew. The result I found is different. Is there an error there?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No error if *gen* and *kill* are correct. + and - are bit-wise logical operators, not arithmetic operators. A + B is A **or** B, and A - B is A **and not** B (bit clear A under bit mask B). That is how set union and set difference are done with bit vectors.

000 1100 + (111 0000 - 110 0001) = 000 1100 + 001 0000 = 001 1100

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you. I was making the mistake of adding the "hand bit" to the other side. I got the correct solution.